# How to select state and city based on country selection in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build 3 dropdown menus for selecting States based on Country selected and City based on State selected.
Now I have code for selecting Country:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :country_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all,:id, :country_name,{prompt: 'Select Country'}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :state_id %>
    <%= form.collection_select(:state_id, State.all,:id, :state_name,{prompt: 'Select State'}) %>
  </div>
```

and my models:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :states
    #has_many :state, :through => :city
end
```

```
class State < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :country
    has_many :cities
end
```

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :state
end
```

Is there anybody can help me with the code of this function with or without ajax? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Great question. I would suggest you get it to work first in a simplified state. Maybe even make a new separate "play" rails application just to work this out. I would suggest getting a form with one drop down to work, then one with two, independent ones to work, and once that's solid, update your question above with a little more detail and we can help you figure out the missing pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax or you will have to store all the states when the page loads up but it will be inappropriate